# Why does Git switch my branches when I have modified files in the working folder?

Tags: git, version-control

I have two branches. I changed some files while on one branch but did not add or commit them. The changes are in my working folder only. The changes are on tracked files but not added or committed, the changes are only in the working folder.

Now I checkedout the other branch and it worked. I'm on the other branch and the changes I made to the files are still in the working folder.

I don't understand the reason for this. I would have expected Git to refuse to switch branch and tell me that I have uncommited changes, that I should commit or stash or do something with them.

I expected the checkout to rewrite my working folder, but my changes are still there.

Why is that? Why are my changes present no matter on what branch I am? Why desn't Git tell me of the presence of modified files in my working folder and refuse to switch branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Branches point to commits. A "change" isn't part of a branch until you make a commit on that branch.

Your working tree and index are not directly attached to a branch, so if you start doing some locally editing and then decide that you really wanted to make this change on a different branch you can check out that branch and carry on working.

Git will refuse to change branches only if you have local modifications (staged or unstaged) which are based on files that are different between the branch that you are switching from and the branch that you are switching to.

Comment: Any way to  configure Git to show a message and not proceed without the user's confirmation?

Comment: No, I don't believe so. You could always write a shell function that does an appropriate diff/status first, though.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably referring to un-tracked files, not changed files. Un-tracked files where never added or committed to any branch, and they stick around when you switch branches.

If you change a tracked file, git won't let you switch branch until you do something with it (commit, discard the change, etc...).

Comment: They are not un-tracked, they are changed. Files existed and were commited on one of the branches. I know un-tracked files stick around but these are modified, tracked files (I updated my question)