# Why aren't my two local branches separate?

Tags: git, branch

I'm having issues understanding why this could be.

I created a new branch `branch1` from my `develop` branch. Made some changes then created a Pull Request for it onto `develop`.

I then created `branch2` from my `develop` branch on which I've been working on.

I now need to make a one line update to `branch1` - following some suggestion on the Pull Request - however when I went to see the differences I noticed it includes all changes in `branch2`.

I would have expected it to only show the branch 1 changes - namely `branch1` and `branch2` be separate.

Any ideas why this isn't the case?
Do I need to do something specific?

Comment: I think you took a wrong step somewhere in your workflow.  Of course, this shouldn't be happening if you really did the steps you described.

Comment: So I thought that at first - i.e. perhaps I create `branch2` from `branch1` not develop. However when I make a change in either `branch1` or `branch2` it appears in both

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen so I think i see what may have happened. When i switch between branch - i.e. `git checkout branch1` or `git checkout branch2` - do I need to commit the changes first? I assumed I could just switch without commiting changes?

Comment: Bingo.  Your changes probably got carried over.  So, you really do have two different branches, but their content has become mixed.  Next time, use `git stash` or make a commit before switching branches.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Yep - just confirmed it by creating another branch. I actually got a dialog stating where I want to 'smart checkout' by IntelliJ. I guess that must have appeared before but I ignored.
Thanks for confirming!

Comment: I didn't know you were doing all this from your IDE.  When working from the command line Git bash, it is harder to make mistakes like this.

Comment: Becuase it would show me what files have been modified??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Git switch my branches when I have modified files in the working folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24913546/why-does-git-switch-my-branches-when-i-have-modified-files-in-the-working-folder)

Answer (score 1):

Per the information you've given you had 2 branches (that were indeed separate from each other) and you had made made changes on branch2 but wanted to modify code in branch1.

> **Your mistake** was **switching branches whilst you had modified files in branch2 still being tracked**, branch2 therefore differed from its HEAD commit and so those changes were being tracked resulting in them being a part of your pull request after working on branch1.

To prevent this you can use [Git Stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) to put all those changes somewhere else temporarily until they are needed again, allowing you work on branch1 with the only tracked changes being modifications to branch1 (as branch2 working directory and index is backed up with git stash)

However, it sounds like you're using an IDE which could potentially be covering up a lot of this process for you, I would recommend looking into stashing/branch switching specifically for that IDE and perhaps attempting to use command line Git just to diagnose problems like this (Git CLI often provides prompts and errors helping you understand why things like this happen).